# A question about extentions of continuous functions on Tychonoff spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let X a Hausdorff Tychonoff space, C a closed subset of X, A a compact subset of int C and B a closed subset of C such that A and B are disjoint. Let f: A---> [0,1] and g: B---> [0,1] be continuous functions. Is it true that there exist a continuous extension h with domain C of both functions f and g? We know that f has such an extension, by compacity of A and X being Tychonoff, can we do that extension in a way to be also an extension of g?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $X$ is totally irrelevant to the question, you might as well assume that $X=C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Indeed, such an extension need not exist even if $A$ is empty, so you are just asking for an extension of $g$.  For instance, let $X=C$ be any Tychonoff space that is not normal (say, the deleted Tychonoff plank) and let $S$ and $T$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X$ that cannot be separated by open sets.  Then the function $g$ on $B=S\cup T$ that is $0$ on $S$ and $1$ on $T$ cannot be extended continuously to $C$.

(Of course, if $X$ is normal then such an extension does always exist by the Tietze extension theorem.)

Comment: Simpler examples are the best, thank you. What about a little modification, say, C being a proper subset of X, A the same and B the boundary of C

Comment: You can just embed my example in a larger space such that $B$ becomes its boundary (for instance take $X=C\times\{0\}\cup B\times[0,1]$).

Comment: Oh, I see. Better made up my mind before any minor modification of my original question. Thanks a lot.